# is it possible to only be able to view a page via email

Tags: email

this may sound a bit funny but what i want to do is lock page from being viewed by typing the url into the address bar so abc.com/defg.php does not output anything but a warning and can only be accessed and view by the link i send my client via email i only ask this on here because i dont know the technical name for this and never worked on getting data from emails

how i would like this to work is:
1. i type in abc.com/defg.php in my web browser and i get a warning saying i don't have the right access to this page

2. i send my client a email with a link that direct to this to abc.com/defg.php
3. this  then sends them to the page after verifying that the link was opened from the email address i originally sent the email to

the reason i want to try do it this way is because i dont want to have to make my clients login to see just one document that once they view the document they can print of or save and i see it as a waste for database memory for one document

so the 3 questions are:
1. can this be done and if it can what is the technical name for this sort of thing so i can do research on this myself 
2. if so can it be done in form of coding EG. php or javascript
3. am i just wasting my time and should shut up and make a login system

Comment: A common way I've seen this done is to include a lengthy, unique GET variable in the URL that is emailed to the client. Then, on your page you read the GET variable and respond accordingly.

Comment: see i thought of that but this will hold some personal data of my clients so if some guess one of the url variables then that means they will see this data it not like bank details or anything like that but it still personal data it meant to be a download or printed off file

Comment: If it's sensitive information you're handling and you're uncomfortable having it (potentially) accessible by an unauthorized user, then doing user authentication through a login would be the better choice. (Although a randomized alphanumeric string that is sufficiently lengthy probably won't be guessed. I'm no security expert, just basing this off of what I've seen some sites do.)

Comment: @Serlite 2-3 dozen alphanumeric characters, and you're looking at several years to brute force all combinations - OP's concern isn't realistic. For added "security," you can make the link expire after a certain amount of time (or after it's been viewed once).

Comment: thank you both of you i take both in to acount